# Container Bluemix Error catalog:createContainer_errorWithIncidentId

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

When I try to create a new Container (MFP) on **Bluemix** I receive this msg: `catalog:createContainer_errorWithIncidentId`

Any suggestions about it this problem?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluemix team is aware of this problem and development team is working on fix now.

In the meantime you can use the command line interface to create a container:

```
$ cf ic run [-p PORT] [-P] [-m MEMORY] [-e ENV] [-v VOLUME:CONTAINER_PATH] --name NAME [--link NAME:ALIAS] [-it] IMAGE [CMD [CMD ...]]
```

You can find more details for the command above in Bluemix docs:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_single_cli